# Check whether an activity is from previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, A & B.

I get some data from webservice in A's `onCreate`. The problem is, when i **press the back button** from B, i come to A but the `onCreate` is not called, which means the data may not be updated.

I know i can use `onResume`, however theres a problem :

I just noticed when activity A was running for the first time, the `onCreate` is called, but so did the `onResume`, which my apps get the data from the webservice twice.

If you dont believe me, just try to Log your `onResume`, you will see it called after `onCreate`

How can i perfectly detect activity A is from activity B, so i can perform certain action from it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No no, I and all Android dev beleve that `onResume` get called after `onCreate`. So what is the problem to write single call into onResume, instead of onCreate?

Comment: We believe you, since it is [what is documented in the official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html). Based on your requirement, it's better to move the code to refresh data inside `onResume()`

Comment: Its my bad, i just realized that onResume() is always called after onCreate(), please answer the question, so other user will know it? I will upvote both of you, Thanks